# trying to add table under measurements but table shows under intro,and 2nd table shows in a different page not under table1?

Tags: tables

```
\section{Introduction}
In this chapter, the results of six different lab groups will be presented. The data is collected from 6 different lab groups and the data is analyzed and finalized by the groups. The test results will be presented in graphs and tables.



\section{Results 1a - Measurements}
Before and during the lab experiment, the data was collected by all six lab groups.

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Group 1:Test Data For LL}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Property                                  & Unit             & Test 1 & Test 2 & Test 3 & Test 4 \\ \hline
Blows (Number of Drops                    & {[}-{]}          & 30     & 17     & 22     & 15     \\ \hline
Oven Can ID                               & {[}-{]}          & 1      & 2      & 3      & 4      \\ \hline
Mass of Oven Can                          & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 63.49  & 62.67  & 62.06  & 62.29  \\ \hline
Mass of Oven Can Lid                      & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 24.84  & 26.09  & 26.33  & 75.79  \\ \hline
Mass of Oven Can, (Lid,) and Wet Soil     & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 70.85  & 73.43  & 77.52  & 75.79  \\ \hline
Mass of Oven Can and, (Lid,) and Dry Soil & {[}g{]} {[}lb{]} & 69.45  & 71.19  & 74.25  & 72.91  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please always provide a small test document that shows the problem, no one can run a fragment as posted here. Note however that the only purpose of the `table` environment is to mark the content as not being part of the main document flow and allowing it to be moved to help with page breaking.

Comment: Related: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/134144)  and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144)